# Зачем использовать серверный рендеринг React.JS компонентов?

Tags: java, reactjs

Это для быстроты просто, чтобы пользователь сразу увидел HTML код?
Я так понимаю для сервера можно использовать не только NODE.JS
но и Java.

Как это будет выглядеть если проект большой? Не будет каши с java, js кода? Кто-то видел большие проекты в такой связке?

Comment: Для поисковиков.

Comment: @andreymal , то есть люди строят изоморфные приложения просто чтобы угодить поисковикам ? Не большое усложнение для одной задачи

Comment: иногда по-другому никак, бывает даже что для поискового бота полностью персональный контент

Comment: @StrangerintheQ мне поисковики например вообще не нужны, мне нужна скорость.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Это для быстроты просто, чтобы пользователь сразу увидел HTML код?

Да, в основном, это делается для того чтобы сократить время отрисовки начальной старницы. Дело в том, что страницы приложений построенных с использованием `React` содержат мало HTML и грузят много `javascript` кода. После загрузки `javascript` страница, как привило, загружает данные с сервера и после этого, собственно, отрисовывает страницу (Отрисовка, кстати, не самая быстрая операция).  Пока `javascript` не загружен и данные не получены, пользователь будет видеть пустую страницу. 
С другой стороны, если сервер отдает готовую страницу, то во первых, создается впечатление что страница грузится быстрее, а во вторых, можно сэкономить на одном или нескольких запросах к серверу, так как все необходимые данные уже загружены.
Стоить иметь ввиду, что броузер все равно будет грузить javascript, и после загрузки React создаст виртуальный DOM страницы, но поскольку он совпадет с кодом сгенерированной страницы то никаких изменений React делать не будет (не надо перерисовывать страницу). В худшем случае часть страницы может изменится после загрузки обновленных данных, но обычно, это не заметно для польователя.

Есть мнение, что сервер может генерировать страницы быстрее чем браузер но я думаю это зависит от того какой сервер и какой компьютер у пользователя. В любом случае преумуществом генерации страницы на сервере будет возможность кеширования страницы сервером, что позволит отдавать ее практически моментально.

> Не будет каши с java, js кода

Нет не будет, хотя добавит немного сложностей. Но тут уж ничего не поделаешь, или быстро или сложно.

Comment: Спасибо! Первый хороший ответ на эту тему. А подскажи, пожалуйста, если уже все скрипты загружены, но страница полностью меняется(с теста на вывод результат, например) - имеет в этом случае использовать серверный рендеринг?

Comment: @O.O что то я не понял вопрос.

Comment: Я же правильно понимаю, что когда пользователь первый раз заходит к нам на сайт - мы генерируем html с привязанными скриптами и отправляем в ответ? Далее react уже сам отвечает за dom. Однако, если dom поменялся кардинально - вместо страницы, например, личного, кабинета, должна появиться страница общего чата - как лучше делать - формировать её на стороне сервера и отправлять готовый html по Ajax или формировать её силами React на стороне клиента? Спасибо!

Comment: Пользователь запрашивает страницу и вы на сервере генерите и возвращаете страницу как она долдна быть, то есть  не то что вы всегда возвращаете домашнюю страницу а возвращаете то что пользователь запросил. Eсли url bala.com/account тогда возвращаемый контент должен содержать личную страницу. Если пользователь потом нажмет на ссылку например на список товаров, тогда уже реакт перерисует страницубез перезагрузки